# Adding pom version number to the Artifactory repository path

Tags: maven, artifactory, concourse, concourse-pipeline

How can I add the `pom.xml` (maven) version number to the Artifactory repository path in the pipeline.

```yaml
resource_types:
  - name: artifactory
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: pivotalservices/artifactory-resource

resources:
  - name: artifactory-racer-webapi-app
    type: artifactory
    check_every: 167h
    source:
      endpoint: https://artifactory.xxxx/artifactory
      repository: "/xxx-libs-releases/xxxx-webapi-app/<version>"
      regex: xxx-webapi-app-(?<version>.*).jar
      username: ((username))
```

Same idea as I did with the regex.

Comment: Do you want to extract the version of the POM to command line?

Comment: Not exactly, I am using Concourse to deploy the artifact. I was assuming that the version number of the pom will be part of the repo path but apparently its not.  I want to add the version number to the pipeline.yml so the repo path will look like "/xxx-libs-releases/xxxx-webapi-ap/0.0.1"

Comment: What do you mean by "repo path"? You have a base path for the repo, a repository and then you get a path that consists of groupId, artifactId and version.

Comment: I mean that the Artifact will be deploy under a directory with the name of the version number that was defined in the pom. For example if version in the pom is <version>0.0.2</version> then the jar will be deploy to this path "/xxx-libs-releases/xxxx-webapi-app/0.0.2".

Comment: If this is a Maven project, then the path inside the repository is fully determined by the groupId, artifactId and version. You cannot influence the path inside the Maven repository.

Comment: Hi Fabian, Yes I agree and this is what I am expect to see eventually in Jfrog. But for some reason the path will be created without the version number. I have no idea what is wrong. I have tried several options in the repo -> "repository: "/xxx-libs-releases/xxxx-webapi-app/???? NO VERSION DIRECTORY"